# PHP+HTML - Regex to deal with names

Tags: php, html, regex

I would like to create a regex to validate customer names.

This would be a name like Peter, André, Mary-Anne or Van Rensberg. Asian characters should not be allowed, along with other characters that do not relate to names of this manner.

This will be validated via the HTML5 pattern attribute and then again via PHP as a last resort.

I originally started off with this: `[^\p{L}\s0-9]{1,120}` which almost applies that I have had in mind, but does not relate exactly to what I am trying to accomplish.

It will basically allow characters like c or é or -, but will not allow spaces and as a side affect allows the input of other special characters like / and %.

Given my very limited knowledge on this subject I thought I would ask this question in order to gain some knowledge from some people that know more than I do.

Thank you for any suggestions of feedback in this regard!

Comment: sorry man, but I can't understand exactly what do you need, could you give us more details

Comment: Please add more info WHY you are validating the names. Also see this essential article: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Please read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) (seems to be down at the moment… might need to try a cache) and then ask yourself what you stand to gain by validating peoples' names. If this is still something you need to do for some reason, then maybe give us some more information what exactly you're trying to validate - what is valid, or conversely, what is invalid.

Comment: @mechdeveloper I have a form that adds certain details about a website user to a database. Part of this is a users first and last name. Given that I would like to briefly check that this information is a name like mentioned. Sorry, do you need more info than this? My customers will all be English speaking and hence the reason for me not wanting the asian characters.

Comment: @chiborg thanks I will read through your link

Comment: @Garrett Albright The link does work, I will read through it now. But basically, I just want to make sure people dont add junk into the name field... This info is displayed again in a profile page, so in essence this would be the first round in a effort to remove tags and other unwanted characters. I do not deal with asian speaking people and would more than likely not be able to work with characters I do not understand in anycase, so I would like this removed.

Comment: [htmlspecialchars()](http://jp2.php.net/htmlspecialchars) and friends can help sanitize your output when it comes to tags and such, but as for the names, I don't think you're giving your visitors enough credit. If your site and your form is all in English, and they can read and understand that English, they're not going to enter 浦島太郎 into the name field of the form - they'll understand that in this context they need to romanize it. (I say this as someone who currently lives in Japan and studies Japanese daily with classmates who are mostly Chinese.)

Comment: @Garrett Albright Thanks, and as I stated this would only be the first round in the attempt. But I guess its kind of a double job. And yes that is true, but how would I know who an order is for? I cant tell the fine details in an Asian charset if they do by chance decide to use it? This would be why I would require an English name.

Comment: Like I said, you're not giving Chinese/Japanese/Korean/Thai/Mongolian/etc folks enough credit. They're not dumb; they know that, if they are entering a form on an English-language site to be read by English-speaking people, they need to romanize their name. They learn how to do this at a very young age. They know that very few people outside of their countries' borders who will be able to read their native script. I'll bet you ten thousand yen that this is not a problem you'll ever have to worry about.

Comment: @GarrettAlbright Hahaha, whats that then? 1c? If so then you're on! I live in a very diverse country where people are coming and going at an amazing rate... If I lived maybe in the U.S. sure this may be true... But I do not think that is will be 100% always the case. I guess I am trying to apply some foresight... But maybe as you said, this is not 100% correct concerning the mindset of the people that I am dealing with. I don't live in China, so...

Comment: @GarrettAlbright Do you think a better bet would be to use a regex to block unwanted characters only? like % or / etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You should start with:*

`/^([\p{Letter}\p{Latin}]+(\-[\p{Letter}\p{Latin}]+|[\x20\xA0\x{0020}\x{00A0}])?)+$/`

*and if needed, you can add other scripts, such as:*

`\p{Hebrew}`*,* `\p{Cyrillic}`*,* `\p{Georgian}`*,* `\p{Greek}`*, etc.*

*For more information check "[Unicode Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)".*

*I suggest you to trim leading/trailing whitespace characters before regex validation*.

Answer (score 1):

if you are going to validate if a name is a name, you should try to validate if that name isn't an invalid string with spaces only or a string with a really short lenght.
if you were expecting a regex to validate names maybe this should work

```
/(^|\s)[A-Za-z\-áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+($|\s)/i
```

but I insist that the better thing that you can do is to make sure that the name isn't an invalid string, because there is a lot of name and last name with many shapes